# Can elements of a collection be moved up or down?

Tags: collections

[image]

Let’s say I want the NM.Top.Soil layer to be above Far.Mountain. I don’t see the way

Comment: No, it's alphabetical.

Comment: This functionality is very much needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is alphabetical, but you can use it as an advantage. 
I frequently use codes at the beginning of my objects names to determine their order, like:

- `"AAA Cube"`
- `"AAB Sphere"`
- `"AAF Empty"`

This way those object will always be at the top of their collection

Comment: This will do the job while that functionality is added. Great idea! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Same here but I use numbers; my brain can parse their sort order more quickly.